# How to know if your algorithm is O(n2)?

Tags: java, big-o

I've created an algorithm but I'm not sure if it's O(n2). I know that having a for loop within a for loop or a nested loop would mean it's O(n2). I'm not sure about this algorithm I've created. For the purpose just knowing the Big O Notation, I'll leave my codes in comments. I'm not using any Collections or API.

```
public class GraphTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int m[][] =
            {
                    //values here...
            };

    if (check(m))
        System.out.print("True");
    else
        System.out.print("False");
}


static int s = 6;


static boolean check(int m[][]) {

    //instances here...


    if (s == 1)
        //return values here...

    if (s == 2)
       // return values here...


    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        //instance variable
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)

        if (){...}

        if (){...}

        else if (){...}

    }

    //return result here
}
```

}

Comment: "*I know that having a for loop within a for loop or a nested loop would mean it's O(n2).*" - Not necessarily. If both loops run in constant-sized steps to `n`, then yes.

Comment: How many times are the instructions inside your nested for loop executed?

Comment: Since s is 6, it's constant no matter what. There will only be 36 runs inside the inner loop. If s depends on the length or width of your array, then it makes sense to calculate O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Consider for example that this for loop is O(n): `for (int i=0; i<s; i++) {//...}`, meaning the complexity increases in a linear way with `s`.
Now, you iterate `s` times in the outer for loop and for each iteration of the outer loop you iterate `s` times, hence the overall number of iterations becomes `s*s`->O(n2). If the second for loop were not nested it would still be O(n).

Comment: Incorrect. The second loop could be nested but with a constant `n`. Lets say 3 so the complexity will be O(n) as well. Or to keep you notation 3*n -> O(n)

Comment: Yes, but if it is nested with `s` and `s` is variable it becomes O(n2)

Comment: It's O(s^2). `s` is declared as a static variable, so unless there's something in the commented-out code doing an assignment like `s = m.length`, then `s` has no relation to the method's *input size*.